# How could i decrypt strings which are encrypted multiple times w.r.t to Following code in Android?

Tags: android, encryption, frida

```
static MediaType f865a = MediaType.parse("application/json");

    private static String f866b = "IV_VALUE_16_BYTE";
    private static String c = "Egov";
    private static String d = "SALT_VALUE";
    private static String e = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1";
    private static String f = "eMethod219";
    private static String g = "AES";
private static String m = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";

    private static String h = "eMethod486";
    private static String i = "eMethod269";
    private static String j = "eMethod580";

private String a(byte[] bArr) {
        return new String(bArr, "UTF-8");
    }

    private Key a() {
        return new SecretKeySpec(SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(e).generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(c.toCharArray(), c(d), 65536, 128)).getEncoded(), g);
    }

    private Cipher a(int i2) {
        Cipher instance = Cipher.getInstance(m);
        instance.init(i2, a(), new IvParameterSpec(c(f866b)));
        return instance;
    }

    private byte[] c(String str) {
        return str.getBytes("UTF-8");
    }

    public String a(String str) {
        Log.d("decode", str);
        return new String(a(2).doFinal(a.b(c(str))));
    }

    public String a(String str, String str2, String str3) {
        String str4;
        IOException e2;
        OkHttpClient build = new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS).writeTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS).readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
        String str5 = k + "/" + h;
        String str6 = "{\"EPara1\":\"" + b(str) + "\", \"EPara2\" :\"" + b(str2) + "\",\"EPara3\" :\"" + b(str3) + "\"}";
        String str7 = "test";
        try {
            str4 = build.newCall(new Request.Builder().url(str5).post(RequestBody.create(f865a, "\"" + b(str6) + "\"")).build()).execute().body().string();
            try {
                Log.d("Encrypt", str4);
            } catch (IOException e3) {
                str7 = str4;
                e2 = e3;
            }
        } catch (IOException e4) {
            e2 = e4;
            e2.printStackTrace();
            str4 = str7;
            str4 = a(str4);
            Log.d("Decrypt", str4);
            return str4;
        }
        try {
            str4 = a(str4);
        } catch (Exception e5) {
            e5.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("Decrypt", str4);
        return str4;
    }
```

So i got this interesting code snippet by decompiling the apk .
Now i used **frida** to monitor and trace ciphers . i tried many times to decrypt the strings that the app uses to make requests to the **API**.I intercepted the request using **Burp suite** but the request body was encrypted. Any ideas on how to decrypt the encryption also the response i get from the request is **encrypted** and decrypted using same **Algo**

Also after **Deobfuscating** the apk i found similar code :

```
private byte[] decode(String str) {
        return str.getBytes("UTF-8");
    }

    private String get(byte[] bArr) {
        return new String(bArr, "UTF-8");
    }

    private Key get() {
        return new SecretKeySpec(SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(value).generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(key.toCharArray(), decode(t), 65536, 128)).getEncoded(), k);
    }

    private Cipher init(int i2) {
        Cipher $r3 = Cipher.getInstance(H);
        $r3.init(i2, get(), new IvParameterSpec(decode(n)));
        return $r3;
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: package-private */
 public String getString(String str, String str2, String str3) {
        IOException $r17;
        OkHttpClient $r6 = new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS).writeTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS).readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
        String $r1 = get(str);
        String $r2 = get(str2);
        String $r7 = get(str3);
        String $r3 = this$0 + "/" + e;
        String $r12 = "{\"EPara1\":\"" + $r1 + "\", \"EPara2\" :\"" + $r2 + "\",\"EPara3\":\"" + $r7 + "\"}";
        String $r13 = "\"" + get($r12) + "\"";
        Log.d("teeeee", $r13);
        String $r22 = "test";
        try {
            String $r14 = $r6.newCall(new Request.Builder().url($r3).post(RequestBody.create(c, $r13)).build()).execute().body().string();
            $r22 = $r14;
            try {
                Log.d("Encrypt", $r14);
            } catch (IOException $r16) {
                $r22 = $r14;
                $r17 = $r16;
            }
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            $r17 = e2;
            $r17.printStackTrace();
            $r22 = read($r22);
            Log.d("Decrypt", $r22);
            return $r22;
        }
        try {
            $r22 = read($r22);
        } catch (Exception $r18) {
            $r18.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("Decrypt", $r22);
        return $r22;
    }


  public String get(String str) {
        try {
            return get(Base64.encodeBase64URLSafe(init(1).doFinal(decode(str))));
        } catch (Throwable $r4) {
            throw new RuntimeException($r4);
        }
    }
```

Comment: And what is your actual problem you have the code for building and initializiing the cipher and the decode method? Is the code complete is a method missing? Otherwise just collect and recombine the different parts of the puzzle. Just reimplement this in a Java program and feed your data in.

Comment: exactly @Robert i am trying to solve this but while using  this [script](https://github.com/m0bilesecurity/Frida-Mobile-Scripts/blob/master/Android/tracer_cipher.js)  i got everything that is being encrypted but when i do the **decryption** using frida i dont get the same **plaintext**

Comment: If you get a decryption result without errors and if the decrypted data looks reasonable you just have not collected the decrypted data at the correct time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some point you'll see the data going into the encryption function so why not just nab it there?

Anyway, here is a snippet from my script. I use frida.send() instead of console.log, might need to modify and add where needed.

```
 var secretKeySpecDef = Java.use('javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec');

 var ivParameterSpecDef = Java.use('javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec');

 var ivParameterSpecDef_init_1 = ivParameterSpecDef.$init.overload('[B');

 var cipherDoFinal_1 = cipherDef.doFinal.overload();
var cipherUpdate_1 = cipherDef.update.overload('[B');

    
var secretKeySpecDef_init_1 = secretKeySpecDef.$init.overload('[B', 'java.lang.String');

    secretKeySpecDef_init_1.implementation = function (arr, alg) {
        send("Creating " + alg + " key plaintext: " + toHexString(arr));
        return secretKeySpecDef_init_1.call(this, arr, alg);
    }

 cipherDoFinal_1.implementation = function () {
        var ret = cipherDoFinal_1.call(this);
        send(this.getIV(), this.getAlgorithm(), complete_bytes, ret);
        // complete_bytes = array used for ciperUpdate. Add your own message
        return ret;
    }

cipherUpdate_1.implementation = function (arr) {
        addtoarray(arr); 
   // Adds to an array object to be used in cipherDoFinal
// Add your own code here
        return cipherUpdate_1.call(this, arr);
    }
```

Comment: it worked hopeffully..but i was testing my college app which shows attendance and all information of the student ...it uses an **api** to communicate with the server and body of the request is being encrypted (now due to ur help it's being decrypted)....**so is there any way that i  can get alll the database?** request and response are in the form of JSON.

Comment: The only way you can get the entire database is by modifying the request that goes to the database. Should be in the form of an SQL statement

Comment: what if it doesn't using SQL database?